# Cancel builder.Prompts.choice()

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

My bot has a prompt that asks for user input:

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Is it ok?", ["Yes", "No"]);
```

Now, when a user responds with something else other than "Yes" or "No" the program will always reply with:

```
I did not understand. Please choose an option from the list
```

with the same choices as before.

I would like the bot to not ask for input again if the user types something else other than "Yes" or "No" (and reset the prompt stack so).

Comment: Nothing? Otherwise I would have wrote it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the maxRetries option for the prompt as shown (default is infinite)

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Is it ok?", ["Yes", "No"],maxRetries:'2');
```

You can see the IPrompt options in the mentioned URL

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ipromptoptions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also capture other specific inputs during a prompt using Trigger Actions (for example "help"):

```
// Add default dialog
bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Is it ok?", ["Yes", "No"]);
});

// Add help dialog with a trigger action bound to a regular 
// expression looking for the users to ask for help.
bot.dialog('/help', function (session) {
    session.endDialog("Type 'Yes' or 'No'");
}).triggerAction({ matches: /^(help|options)/i });
```

Note you'll need to install the pre-release version of BotBuilder:

```
npm install --save botbuilder@next
```